# Jupyterhub for local network users

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, jupyterhub

I am new to the jupyterhub framework so I would appreciate some help with how to go about this - 
I have a script running on my local machine on some data (also stored locally).

Example case: sales forecasts for different stores. 
I use jupyter notebook to display the visualizations using some widgets. These visualizations are interactive and the user can choose the store and timeperiod for which they want to compare the actual sales and forecasts.

Can/how do I achieve this using jupyterhub? 
Is it possible to host the notebook through my local machine?
The people who want to view the visualizations are not tech-people so can they access the notebook without having to install the dependencies- jupyterhub/python/jupyter notebook?

Also, as per the tutorials I browsed [here](https://github.com/minrk/jupyterhub-pydata-2016/blob/master/JupyterHub.pdf) "Jupyterhub spawns single-user notebook servers" - but what does that mean? 
Do the servers come with a copy of the sales data uploaded or that they have access to the data stored on my local machine.

Comment: Please add a link to the tutorial.

Comment: Added the link to the tutorial